# Conflicting performance using Image acquisition GUI and the exported HDevelop code

Tags: halcon

I have a setup with a camera and a flash system, which when used with the Image acquisition GUI within HDevelop gives me proper performance. i.e, image capture with the flash triggered once. I go to the Code generation tab and export the code for the same, and when executing I get another performance. i.e. image captured with the flash triggered twice. I have been unable to pinpoint the issue.

Below is the code exported using the above mentioned Code Generation tab GUI

```
open_framegrabber ('GigEVision', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'default', -1, 'default', -1, 'false', 'default', camID , 0, -1, AcqHandle)
set_framegrabber_param (AcqHandle, 'DeviceTemperatureSelector', 'Main')
set_framegrabber_param (AcqHandle, 'TriggerSelector', 'FrameStart')
set_framegrabber_param (AcqHandle, 'EventSelector', 'AcquisitionStart')
set_framegrabber_param (AcqHandle, 'bits_per_channel', -1)
* Image Acquisition 01: Attention: The initialization may fail in case parameters need to
set_framegrabber_param (AcqHandle, 'AcquisitionMode', 'SingleFrame')
grab_image_start (AcqHandle, -1)
grab_image_async (Image, AcqHandle, -1)
* Image Acquisition 01: Do something
close_framegrabber (AcqHandle)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what is happening you need to know about the two different ways of acquiring images HALCON has, a synchronous and an asynchronous one. And also how the parameter *AcquisitionMode* influences the acquisition on the camera itself.

### AcquisitionMode

For GigE Vision cameras the default value for *AcquisitionMode* that is mandatory for the camera to have is 'Continuous'. Other possible values are 'SingleFrame' (which you are using in the code you posted) and 'MultiFrame' (which I will omit for now).

**Continuous**

In this mode the camera is continuously acquiring images until it is told to stop doing so. After one image is acquired, either the acquisition of the next frame starts directly, or if the camera is set to a specific frame-rate the camera waits until it needs to acquire the next image according to its settings.

**SingleFrame**

In this mode the camera acquires one image and then pauses the acquisition until it is told to acquire the next image.

### Synchronous grabbing

The operator `grab_image` is used to acquire an image. When this operator is executed the following steps are performed:

1. If any images are still in any internal buffer they are discarded.
2. The camera is told to start the acquisition.
3. After an image is acquired, the camera is told to stop the acquisition.
4. The image is transferred and returned by the `grab_image` operator

The benefit of using synchronous grabbing is that you will always get an image that was acquired by the camera after you called the operator. The downside is, that emptying the buffers and starting/stopping the acquisition on the camera takes time, so it will not always be possible to reach the maximum frame-rate of a camera with this mode. Another downside is that when you are using an external trigger for your camera it can happen that you loose trigger signals when grabbing synchronously. This can happen when the trigger signal is activated before the call of `grab_image`. At this point the camera is not acquiring and the trigger signal is ignored.

If you are using the Image Acquisition Assistant this is what happens when you press the Snap button. In your setup this would mean that for a single `grab_image` call you will see the flash fire once.

### Asynchronous grabbing

The relevant operators are `grab_image_start` and `grab_image_async`. There is also one more parameter *start_async_after_grab_async* that is important and that is set to 'enabled' by default.

As in the code you posted you usually first call `grab_image_start` which starts the acquisition on the camera, but does not stop it after the first image is acquired. What the camera does next depends on the setting of the *AcquisitionMode* ('Continuous': it keeps on acquiring, 'SingleFrame': it waits for a signal to start the next acquisition). All images the camera acquires are sent to HALCON and stored in a queue of buffers. When you call `grab_image_async` the oldest image in the buffer queue is retrieved. If *start_async_after_grab_async* is set to 'enabled', immediately after `grab_image_async` retrieves the image a command is sent to the camera to acquire the next image. In case of calling `grab_image_async` before calling `grab_image_start`, `grab_image_async` internally calls `grab_image_start`.

The benefit of asynchronous grabbing is that (at least in 'Continuous' mode) acquisition is always active and it is more unlikely to loose trigger signals. The downside is that you might retrieve an older image from the buffer queue or that at some point the queue is full when images are not retrieved fast enough. This of course  happens when the image processing takes longer than the delay between the acquisition of the images.

Asynchronous grabbing is also what the Image Acquisition Assistant does when you press the Live instead of the Snap button.

### The generated code

Now we can have a look at what happens in the code you posted. You are using `grab_image_start`, `grab_image_async`, *AquisitionMode* is set to 'SingleFrame' and *start_async_after_grab_async* is set to 'enable'.

1. `grab_image_start` is called and acquisition is started on the camera. The flash fires once when the image is acquired. Because of the 'SingleFrame' mode the camera then pauses the acquisition.
2. `grab_image_async` is called and the image that was acquired when the flash first fired is returned. Because acquisition was not stopped, only paused, on the camera and because *start_async_after_grab_async* is enabled a command is sent to the camera to start the next acquisition. So the flash fires a second time when the next image is acquired and then the camera again waits for the next command.

**tl;dr**

If you want the camera to only acquire one single image and then stop, you just need to replace the lines

```
grab_image_start (AcqHandle, -1)
grab_image_async (Image, AcqHandle, -1)
```

with the single line

```
grab_image (Image, AcqHandle)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, that explanation really helped me. Basically what you suggested was to use the synchronous mode of image capture, which in fact causes the flash to fire once. 

The same implementation of single flash in asynchronous mode would be setting the start_async_after_grab_async to 'disable' and  then grab_image_async, right? P.S. I have tried it and it does in fact fire the flash once